# How to style a span content tag using inline styles

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a span with inline styles for an email:

```
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 16;"></span>
```

In my helper I have tried this:

```
content_tag(:span, style: "display: inline-block; width: 16;")
```

The words "display: inline-block; width: 16;" are displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
content_tag(:span, nil, style: "display: inline-block; width: 16;")
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag